# Как вывести список городов с кол-во пользователей в каждом из городов?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `city` (id, name) и есть таблица `user` (id, name, city_id)

Делаю запрос:

```
SELECT city.name AS 'город', COUNT(user.city_id) AS 'кол-во пользователей' 
    FROM city RIGHT JOIN user ON city.id = user.city_id
```

на выходе только первый город с общим кол-вом пользователей по всем городам.

Нужно вывести список всех городов с кол-вом пользователей в каждом из этих городов, например:

```
Москва 10
Ростов 5
Волгоград 3
и т.д.
```

Comment: добавьте group by, пересчислив в нем все колонки, которые не должны суммироваться, т.е. которые определеяют одну выходную строку (в данном случае город). Без явного указания group by применение count() приводит к группировке до 1 строки

Comment: добавил, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT city.name AS 'город', COUNT(user.id) AS 'кол-во пользователей' 
FROM city 
INNER JOIN user ON city.id = user.city_id
Group By city.name
```

Comment: добавил, спасибо